# Application "Near Cache" data does not invalidated upon change in central Hazelcast server

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast

Hazelcast 3.12.4 is deployed in Kubernetes 1.21 along with other Applications.

Whenever any application instance updates the cache in the central Hazelcast, an event is triggered and sent to all the Application instances which have stored that data as in-memory Near Cache.

The application invalidates the Near Cache data upon receiving this event from central Hazelcast so that it can fetch the latest data from the central Hazelcast cache.

It is observed that sometimes Hazelcast events are not received or not processed by a few application instances and hence the application's cached data does not get updated.

Because of this issue, few application instances have latest data in their Near Cache while some application instances have stale data in their Near Cache.

This issue is randomly occurring and no specific steps are observed to reproduce this issue.

Following is the hazelcast-client xml:

```
<hazelcast-client xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config
              http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config/hazelcast-client-config-5.1.xsd">

<cluster-name>dev</cluster-name>
<instance-name>UPC</instance-name>
<properties>
    <property name="hazelcast.client.shuffle.member.list">true</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.client.heartbeat.timeout">600000</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.client.heartbeat.interval">180000</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.client.event.queue.capacity">1000000</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.client.invocation.timeout.seconds">120</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.client.statistics.enabled">false</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.discovery.enabled">false</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.invalidation.reconciliation.interval.seconds">31</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.invalidation.max.tolerated.miss.count">1</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.map.invalidation.batch.enabled">true</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.map.invalidation.batch.size">5</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.map.invalidation.batchfrequency.seconds">5</property>
</properties>

<network>
    <cluster-members>
        <address>10.151.32.200:31050</address>
    </cluster-members>

    <discovery-strategies>
        <discovery-strategy enabled="false"
            class="com.hazelcast.kubernetes.HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategy">
            <properties>
                <!-- configure discovery service API lookup -->
                <property name="service-name">hazelcast</property>
                <property name="namespace">default</property>
            </properties>
        </discovery-strategy>
    </discovery-strategies>
    <smart-routing>true</smart-routing>
    <redo-operation>true</redo-operation>
    <connection-timeout>90000</connection-timeout>

</network>

<near-cache name="default">
            <in-memory-format>OBJECT</in-memory-format>
            <serialize-keys>true</serialize-keys>
            <invalidate-on-change>true</invalidate-on-change>
            <eviction eviction-policy="NONE" max-size-policy="ENTRY_COUNT"/>
</near-cache>
    
<connection-strategy async-start="false" reconnect-mode="ASYNC">
    <connection-retry>
        <initial-backoff-millis>2000</initial-backoff-millis>
        <max-backoff-millis>60000</max-backoff-millis>
        <multiplier>3</multiplier>
        <cluster-connect-timeout-millis>5000</cluster-connect-timeout-millis>
        <jitter>0.5</jitter>
    </connection-retry>
</connection-strategy>
```

Comment: Does it do this with the latest version ? (currently 5.1.3). There have been a few bug fixes since 3.12.4 (eg. https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/19108)

Comment: which Hazelcast jar version needs to be used for 5.1.3?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hazelcast/hazelcast-all ------as per this link, 5.0-BETA-1 is the latest available library

Comment: Also, what about Hazelcast client version? ......   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hazelcast/hazelcast-client .... as per this link, 3.12.12 is the latest version

Comment: Use `com.hazelcast:hazelcast:5.1.3`. `hazelcast-all` is no longer used, hence there isn't a 5.1.3 version of this. The features that were in it are now included in the main download. It's unlikey Kubernetes is connected to the behaviour you see, which may make it easier to retest.

Comment: We were able to integrate with Hazelcast 5.1.3 from the application. But post integration, the latency has increased drastically to 10x. I have added hazelcast-client xml in the main section.

Comment: Latency changing is a separate problem. Are you able to create an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show it ?

Comment: Yes. I can share the mvce. Let me know how/where to share it.

Comment: Are you on Hazelcast's community Slack ?  https://hazelcast.com/dev-community/  You could find me on there and send me a DM

Comment: Was this ever submitted as a bug? Or was the exampe code ever made public? I'm experiencing a very similar bug and I'd love to know if this was ever addressed or fixed